# std::vector performance for pixel buffers

Tags: c++, performance

Doing software 2d pixel buffers, blitting, etc. Someone was telling me there's absolutely no overhead involved in using an std::vector to represent objects, I was wondering if std::vector is indeed a good container for pixel buffers or if I should instead stick with a raw array like I've always used.

Thanks

Comment: I'd say, try it. or look at this question's answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740020/c-stl-array-vs-vector-raw-element-accessing-performance

Comment: What I would say: profile it :)
But in any case, if your raw array is dynamically allocated, there won't be any noticeable overhead (if any) when using an std::vector instead. 
However, keep in mind that the debug version of an std::vector probably has some additional checks which might make it look slower.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When used properly, there shouldn't be any overhead in performance. But, they aren't exactly zero-overhead compared to raw arrays.

**Size overhead**

A typical std::vector container will use 3 pointers. Since you probably already track width and height yourself, your raw array could be done in one pointer since you already know the size.

**Allocation overhead**

You will incur some overhead when allocating the memory for the std::vector. However, this is the same overhead you incur if you allocate your own memory.

**Zero-initialization overhead**

std::vector will actually zero-init your memory when using resize(), which may or may not be significant to what you're doing.

But, from a performance standpoint, accessing a std::vector is the same as accessing an array.

Comment: zero-initializing using resize() is important, never knew that, thanks

Comment: Except in debug mode, where most testing will be done.  The difference between std:: vector and a plain array can be massive, depending on compiler/library vendor and options.  We actually ban all use of STl containers an write our own, just to ensure minimal overhead in debuggable builds.

Answer (score 3):

When you use an std::vector, it is basically a thin wrapper around an array, which itself is basically just a block of values much like any other buffer. But the real question is why you want to do this? An std::vector is an improvement over a normal array mostly in that you can resize it by adding and removing values - but this is not an operation you would normally perform on a pixel buffer. So the vector seems to give you no benefit here.

These days you rarely use an array of pixels anyway, since most graphics are handled more efficiently using a library-specific type that is suited to the underlying hardware.

Comment: One good reason to use a vector is that it will automatically free its memory on destruction.

Comment: So do arrays...

Comment: Not in C++, not if they're dynamically allocated, they don't.

Comment: That's only a concern if you don't know the size in advance, which you usually do if you're performing low level pixel operations.

Comment: You'd have to know the size at *compile time* to use static allocation.  So you're proposing that the pixel sizes of all art assets and render targets be hard-coded into your game?  Frankly, that sounds dumb.

Comment: Really I'm proposing using whatever the API gives you for graphics surfaces. If you're using std::vector for your graphics and handling pixels directly yourself then it's very rare you're doing anything other than a toy project or simple experiment where the concept of art assets or variable resolution is rather uncommon. But sure, std::vector is more convenient if you don't mind your debug builds being a bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to use an `std::vector` for pixel data as long as you're careful not to allocate/deallocate/copy memory unnecessarily.  For example, when you create a pixel buffer, use the vector's `resize` method to set it to the number of pixels required, then don't change its size afterward.  When passing buffers around from one function to another, use a pointer or reference to the vector rather than passing by value.  If you need to assign one vector to another, use the `swap` method where possible to avoid unnecessary copies.

In release builds there should be no overhead in accessing individual pixels using the vector's `operator[]`; as xcrypt mentioned in his comment, there could be some overhead in debug builds since the vector might insert range checks.